# Activating a steam gift from Russia failed. Now it says the gift would already have been used

Tags: steam

I got a Steam gift key from a russian friend. I opened the link he sent me and it said that the game could not be activated in Germany. So i fired up a VPN and when I opened the Link again, it said the link was already used.
Can I do anything about it?

Comment: You can no longer receive Steam gifts from regions outside your own, I believe.  Was this actually a friend, or did you buy a game from a game reseller?

Comment: Actually a friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All games purchased on Steam in Russia and CIS are now region locked. All of them. Yes, your game too. RT. [pic.twitter.com/N5urUgOeEq](http://t.co/N5urUgOeEq)

— Tomáš Duda (@tomasduda) [December 17, 2014](https://twitter.com/tomasduda/status/545031478242205696)

---

### Reddit post about [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/Games/comments/2pjdgd/all_steam_gifts_from_russiacissoutheast_asiasouth/).

---

There is no way of using the gift card to get games due to new policies made by Steam. All Russian Steam games are region locked now.

Comment: Re-Edited the answer.

Comment: Relevant headline and article: ["Steam is region-locking PC games to thwart low currency value exploits" - engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2014/12/17/steam-region-locking/)